# Reference sibling of parent class

Tags: python, scope, reference, flake8, python-typing

I'm trying to define a type definition (pyi) file. In the module I am describing, there is a class that has members that are of a type that is a member of the parent class (see the code snippet below for a clearer explanation). My question is, if `Widget` is defined before `Dialog`, why does `Widget` raise a flake8 "undefined name" error when referenced inside `Dialog`? How can I properly reference `Widget`?

```py
    class types():
        class Widget():
            ...

        class Dialog():
            def __getattr__(name) -> Widget:
                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference `Widget`as `'Widget'` (python 3.7):

```
class types():
    class Widget():
        ...

    class Dialog():
        def __getattr__(name) -> 'Widget':
            ...
```

I am unsure why it is necessary in this particular case.

[Edit]: maybe type hints are a bit ahead of linters for some corner cases; disregarding the linter, this syntax does not throw an error whereas the one you posted does throw a NameError: name 'Widget' is not defined.

OTH, this works:

```
class Widget:
    pass

class Dialog:
    def __getattr__(name) -> Widget:
        pass
```

Comment: I get the same error with this method as I do with the original.

Comment: ok, thank you for the feedback; maybe type hints are a bit ahead of linters for some corner cases; disregarding the linter, this syntax does not throw an error whereas the one you posted does throw a `NameError: name 'Widget' is not defined`.